# How do we know whether $\lim \limits_{x \to c}f(x) $ exists or nor when $f(c)$ doesn't exists?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was doing some limit exercises involving trigonometry functions the question was about solving  $\lim \limits_{x \to \pi} \cot x$.

Now, $\cot x$ is not defined but that shouldn't necessarily mean its limit doesn't exist. I know it doesn't because it has a vertical asymptote. I knew that because $\cot x$ is a very well known function and almost everyone has encountered its graph before.

But there's many, many functions that aren't defined at a point but their limits exist. So my question is, is there a way to know whether it's just $f(c)$ that doesn't exist or if $\lim \limits_{x \to c} f(x)$ doesn't exist either given that one doesn't have access to the function's graph? Is there a form that always implies a limit doesn't exist?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Find the left and right hand limits...

Comment: @Ak19 Thanks! I don't know how I didn't see that... Add this as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: No problem! It's just a hint. Let it be as a comment itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is only one way: Either calculate the limit, or show that there is no limit.

As you say, there are many functions out there. And there are many limit calculation techniques, and a large collection of limit existence and non-existence techniques (they show that a limit exists or not, but doesn't tell you what it is). Which one is suitable to use depends entirely on which function you have.